# Type 'Scripting.FileSystemObject' is not defined

Tags: .net, vb.net, scripting, migration, filesystemobject

I have migrated a VB project from 2008 to 2012. As expected, there are many code modification to meet the migration process. As stated in the title, how can I resolved this error?

Here is the line having the said error:

```
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

Comment: What you replace that with largely depends on what you were using it for.

Comment: What do you mean about replacing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your error you need to add a reference to the `FileSystemObject`:

`Project>Properties>References>Add>COM>Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

But there is absolutely no need to use the FileSystemObject to use the file system.

You can use the fully managed methods in the `File` class in the `System.IO` namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for this informative answer! Now, I understand the flow. Currently using the File class.